# Another comments-like section restricted to particular group

Tags: jira

Is it possible to have another comments-like section restricted to particular group in JIRA issues?

My idea is to have one comments stream for internal communication, and another for communication with customer.

Or is there some other way how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Is there anything wrong with using the existing single comments section with Security Levels applied to individual comments? See https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Commenting+on+an+Issue (search for "viewing restrictions").

Comment: Hi this is the way how we have it today. But users makes relatively a lot of mistakes. This is why I want separate stream for internal communication.

Comment: We have two different approaches for this problem [in different projects]. 1) we only send out external communications with the JETI plugin. 2) There are escalation issues created with a different issue type (and linked, of course).